# Redirect link of old webpage to new webpage in Joomla 2.5

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, joomla

I have modified my website `www.vidyaniketan.in`. It is a Joomla 2.5 site. When I search for it in Google by URL, there are several sub-links displayed (e.g., "ABOUT US"). this links to the old webpage. How do I link it to new webpage? I tried following code in my *.htaccess* file:

```
Redirect 301 /about_us.html http://www.vidyaniketan.in/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71&Itemid=468
```

but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: That redirect appears to be working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you will need to wait for Google to re-index your website.

In Joomla 2.5 though you don't need to hack the `.htaccess` file everytime you restructure your site or move an article. Simply add the desired redirect to the Redirect component (you may also need to enable the `Redirect` plugin).

To use it navigate to `Components—>Redirect` and you can add new redirects there. After a while you will also see other failed requests to your website, the large majority will be people trying to hack your site by looking for unsecured software installations.

Comment: Interesting. So does “Components—>Redirect” handle the creation of `.htaccess` rewrite rules? Or is that application level redirection within the PHO framework of Joomla 2.5.

Comment: Joomla CMS level, above the Framework.

Comment: @cppl Thanks a lot , I wasnt aware about this, it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You've made the redirect correctly. It works well. However you must wait until Google recrawl and reindex it before it appears on search results.